# Effects of a wire's radius

Tags: nuclear-physics, radiation, particle-detectors

I have recently read a paper by R. G. Markham titled "High Resolution Position-Sensitive Proportional Counter." In this paper, the author stated that

"The guard wires were chosen to have a large enough radius to insure no multiplication when biased at the appropriate voltage to give them the same charge per unit length as the active wires."

As stated above, if I pick a large enough radius wire, then no amplification will occur. However, I am a bit unsure how this process works (i.e., even if the wire is bigger, it should still have the same bias as the active wires, so why doesn't it cause the electron avalanche?). If you can explain it to me, I will be very grateful.

Background information: Proportional counter (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proportional_counter). For the counter in the paper, the author uses 5 active wires (these are responsible for causing the electron avalanches), and 4 guard wires (these are responsible for correcting the E field at the edges active wires).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> even if the wire is bigger, it should still have the same bias as the
>   active wires, so why doesn't it cause the electron avalanche?

Even if the bias (voltage) of thin active wires and thick guard wires is the same, the field strength will be distributed differently, with particularly strong field concentrated near thin wires.

Given,  some mean free path, the probability of the ionization and, therefore, of an avalanche, depends on the strength of the local electric field - not on the total potential difference between some point in the chamber and the wires.

This is because, electrons do not continuously accumulate kinetic energy as they drift toward the wires, but rather speed up, collide with gas molecules losing some/most of their kinetic energy and then speed up again.

So, the ionization is most likely in the immediate proximity of thin active wires, where the local electric field is the strongest and where electrons can gain sufficient kinetic energy between two collisions.